# How to calculate percentage of green and the percentage of blue in the images, array already made, for loop reading the image file

Tags: python, arrays, image, colors, percentage

So I have already been able to read the file and produce an array.  I'm struggling finding ways to find the percent of green and blue in an image.

```
#Import Libraries 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob

#option comd c and then cmd v to paste path /Users/Gilly/Desktop/Comp 180/images
#2 Reads the image of a sunset into an array LOOP

list_files=glob.glob("/Users/Gilly/Desktop/Comp 180/images/*.jpg")

for i in list_files:
    img = mpimg.imread(i)
    print(img)

#Plots the image from the array data 

for i in list_files:
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

#Calculate % of Green and Blue in the images
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.
In this case, what have you found in your research on identifying color regions?  Where is your coding attempt?

Comment: I got it thank you anyways, I had many attempts I didn't know I had to post that.

Answer (score 1):

```
emptyBlue = []
emptyGreen= []
for i in list_files:
    img = mpimg.imread(i)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    RGBtuple = np.array(img).mean(axis=(0,1))
    averageRed = RGBtuple[0]
    averageGreen = RGBtuple[1]
    averageBlue = RGBtuple[2]
    percentageGreen = averageGreen/(averageRed+averageGreen+averageBlue)
    percentageBlue = averageBlue/(averageRed+averageGreen+averageBlue)
    percentageRed = averageRed/(averageRed+averageGreen+averageBlue)
    emptyBlue+=[percentageBlue]
    emptyGreen+=[percentageGreen]
    print('Percent Blue',percentageBlue)
    print('Percent Green',percentageGreen)
print('Percentages of Blue',emptyBlue)
print('Percentages of Green',emptyGreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a hint to get you started.

To find the average blue value, you'll have to iterate through every pixel in the image. The image you are working with (stored in the img variable) is a list of rows and each row is a list of pixels.

A nested for loop will let you iterate through every pixel:

```
for row in img:
    for pixel in row:
        red = pixel[0]
        green = pixel[1]
        blue = pixel[2]
        print(blue)
```

If you get stuck, remember `average = total / count`.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get it, i ended up doing things using something similar